# Loop through a dataframe, retrieve column header name, and then use it as parameter in ggplot

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

Hi Please help me on this

I have a dataframe with header

```
csvfile
experiment control par1 par2 par3
1          a        1    11   21 
1          b        5    12   21
2          a        2    11   50 
2          b        3    13   31
3          a        4    11   35
3          b        2    11   35
```

so I want to loop through the column name (except the experiment and control)

```
for (i in column_name)
{
  if (i !="experiment" &  i !="control )
  {filename = paste(i, 'plot.jpg', sep = '_')
  save_path = paste('/filepath', filename, sep='/')
  print(csvfiles$i) 
  jpeg(save_path, width = 1083, height = 643)

  p1 <- ggplot(csvfiles, aes(x=control, y= i, color = control)) + geom_violin() + geom_boxplot(width = 0.1) 
  print(p1)
  dev.off()
  }

  }
```

now I see the problem R is thinking y = i = string instead of looking at the dataframe[i]
since print(csvfiles$i) -> NULL

how do I fix this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create a function, use some non-standard evaluation to access column names from data

```
library(ggplot2)

create_plots <- function(data, col) {
  filename = paste(col, 'plot.jpg', sep = '_')
  save_path = paste('/filepath', filename, sep='/')
  jpeg(save_path, width = 1083, height = 643)

  p1 <- ggplot(data, aes(x=control, y= !!sym(col), color = control)) + 
        geom_violin() + geom_boxplot(width = 0.1) 
  print(p1)
  dev.off()
}
```

and apply it to to different column names using `lapply`

```
cols <- names(df)[!names(df) %in% c('experiment', 'control')]
lapply(cols, create_plots, data = df)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works really well. What does !!sym do?

Comment: @NormanKuo When we pass `cols`, they are just strings. By using `!!sym` we let R know that it has to be treated as column of `data` dataframe.